# How can I speed up this multimatch elasticsearch query?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, match, query-optimization, elasticsearch-query

How can I speed up this elasticsearch query?
I have found that specifying a small set of fields in multi_match.fields helps. What else can I do?
Here is the query... and below is the index mapping.
There are 8million+ records in the index.

By the way, I sometimes include aggregations in my queries. I found that lazy loading the aggregations helps improve the performance of the aggregation portion.

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 26,
"timeout": "60s",
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "a",
                    "fields": [
                        "firstname",
                        "lastname",
                        "home_address1",
                        "home_zip",
                        "home_city"
                    ],
                    "type": "phrase_prefix",
                    "operator": "OR",
                    "slop": 0,
                    "prefix_length": 0,
                    "max_expansions": 50,
                    "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                    "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                    "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                    "boost": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "boost": 1
    }
},
"_source": {
    "includes": [
        "firstname",
        "lastname",
        "home_address1",
        "home_city"
    ],
    "excludes": []
},
"sort": [
    {
        "firstname.keyword": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Here is the index mapping:

```
{
    "contacts_3_w0iuvbowu5": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "contact_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "created": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "date_of_birth": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "dist_congress": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "dist_precinct": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "dist_state_house": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "dist_state_senate": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "dist_ward_township": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "email": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "firstname": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "eager_global_ordinals": true,
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fulltext": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_address1": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "eager_global_ordinals": true,
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_address2": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_city": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "eager_global_ordinals": true,
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_house_num": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_phone": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_postdirection": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_predirection": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_state": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_street_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_street_type": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "home_zip": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "eager_global_ordinals": true,
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "imported": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lastname": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "eager_global_ordinals": true,
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "list_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "middlename": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "registration_date": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "registration_status": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sex": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "state_voter_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "suffix": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: searching for `a` doesn't make sense, what is your use case? can you provide some of your sample documents and what type of search you want to perform. Also timeout 60 second is huge

Comment: Also, what does lazy-loading-aggregations mean?

Comment: In this example, we are searching for documents containing the "a" as a prefix. This link explains lazy-loading aggregations. https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-optimizing-elasticsearch-searches

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts:

1. You are not including zip in the _source, but you still allow search upon this field. Is this something you need in your business case?
2. You are applying sort during your search. You could apply the sort order during index time. Check this part of the documentation, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules-index-sorting.html . Also, setting `track_total_hits` to false, might bring some improvement.
3. Consider adding some prefix_length. You could set it to 2. In most cases it doesn't really affect the user experience.
4. auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query, do you need this? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html . If you do not then set it to false.
5. You can also consider reducing `max_expansions`. Either reduce it overall, or reduce it based on the length of your input (on application level). Basically if you have something like `a`, you can just have it to 20 or 30. No need to go as high as 50, the results (ux-wise) will not really be helpful either way.

Comment: Applying sort order during index time is a good idea when the results will only ever be sorted by one field. However, we allow users to select the sort field and ascending/descending order. Is there still a way to apply sort order at index time that would help us even in this scenario?

Comment: We need to display the total number of hits in our UI. In order to display an accurate count, we need to ensure we capture all of the hits. This means  we need t set max_expansions to a high value. Actually, the max allowed value of 1024 isn't even high enough to capture all of the hits and this is problematic in its own regard.

Comment: @GNG Sorting on index time doesn't prevent you from resorting by another field on query time AFAIK. Haven't used it though. I understand that not all changes are applicable to your business needs (I cannnot know the exact functionality you need) so I just added everything I could locate.